# ruby on rails looping through a list of key value elements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a list of key value pairs like this.

```
  PERSON_SUMMARY = {
      first_names: %w(Mike Tim Jim kevin Alan Sara John Sammy t'Renée),
      last_names: %w(Robinson Jackson Fox Terry Ali Brits Tyson Willis-St.\ Paul),
      offenses: [
        { offense_name:'Speeding', 
          penalties: [
            { penalty_name: 'Prison', severity: 'Medium' },
            { penalty_name: 'Ticket', severity: 'Low' }
          ]
        },
         { offense_name:'Shoplifting', 
          penalties: [
            { penalty_name: 'Prison', severity: 'Medium' },
            { penalty_name: 'Fine', severity: 'Low' }
          ]
        }
      ]
  }
```

I want to store and print only **offense_name**,**penalty_name** and **severity** one by one , but I am not able to get the right syntax.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
PERSON_SUMMARY[:offenses].each do |offense|
      offense_name = offense[:offense_name]
      offense[:penalties].each do |penalty|
        penalty_name = penalty[:penalty_name]
        severity_val = penalty[:severity]
      end
end
```

EDIT: Eventually I need to insert it into the database table through this function:

```
PersonOffense.where(person_id: person.id).first_or_create(
          name: offense_name,
          penalty: penalty_name ,
          severity: severity_val
      end
```

But I notice an issue, there are multiple penalty names above. Not sure how to insert them.

For example,
I need to insert offense_name twice in my table so that there are 2 entries in the table.

```
Speeding Prison Medium

Speeding Ticket Low
```

EDIT: I like Jesse's answer below. How can I use it to insert it in the same order to my method above (inserting offense_name,penalty_name and severity with the result of the answer given below by Jesse.

Comment: what is not working with your solution? what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Like i mentioned above I am trying to store and print offense_name, penalty_name and severity. I am getting this error  syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')' on the last line above

Comment: hmm, your solution runs fine for me (except for the é character in Renée)

Comment: my bad..the function at top of my code had a bracket missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than just using each, if you map over the offenses, and then flatten them in the end, you'll get what you want:

```
offenses = PERSON_SUMMARY[:offenses].map do |offense|
  offense[:penalties].map do |penalty|
    penalty.merge(name: offense[:offense_name])
  end
end.flatten

=> [{:penalty_name=>"Prison", :severity=>"Medium", :name=>"Speeding"}, {:penalty_name=>"Ticket", :severity=>"Low", :name=>"Speeding"}, {:penalty_name=>"Prison", :severity=>"Medium", :name=>"Shoplifting"}, {:penalty_name=>"Fine", :severity=>"Low", :name=>"Shoplifting"}]
```

UPDATE

In ruby, the following is a hash, and you already have a hash [image]

So you can just loop through your new array and create your PersonOffense:

```
offenses.each do |hash|
  PersonOffense.where(person_id: person.id).first_or_create( hash )
end
```

Comment: can you see my edit. I need lil help with this as i am very new to ruby